# Magical record - data key path

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I used this [article](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/)! to understand array import wrapper in magical record.
I want to use dataKeyPath support to load associated image URL directly in my model.

### An example of json entry:

```
{
  "attachments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "url": "http://www.website.net/uploads/2013/10/image.png",
      "title": "imageTitle",
      "mime_type": "image/png",
      "images": {
        "full": {
          "url": "http://www.website.net/uploads/2013/10/image-540x401.png",
          "width": 540,
          "height": 401
        },
        "thumbnail": {
          "url": "http://www.website.net/uploads/2013/10/image-150x150.png",
          "width": 150,
          "height": 150
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Core data mapping

In my core data model, I use a model Attachement with an attribute imageFull associated with the "mappedKeyName" with value "images.full.url".

### Crash on import

When the image is defined all is well imported. The problems is when I have this:

```
{
  "attachments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "url": "http://www.website.net/uploads/2013/10/image.png",
      "title": "imageTitle",
      "mime_type": "image/png",
      "images": {

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case I have a this error :

```
Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "imageFull"; desired type = NSString;   given type = __NSArrayI;
```

In this method when it trying to map values:

```
- (void) MR_setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forKeysWithObject:(id)objectData
```

the problem is that instead of returning an empty string or nil it's returning the empty images data.

Do you think it's my way to load that is wrong ? is there an other way to do this ? or do I have to do it manually ?

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

MagicalRecord allows you to use your own import methods with the following signature:

```
- (BOOL)import<attributeName>:(id)data
```

you can define one in your Attachment class. This approach is described in article you mentioned. Code may look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)importImageFull:(id)data { 
    if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        self.imageFull = data;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```